# Using ASP.Net MVC access data using entity framework getting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am written code in asp.net mvc to access data using entity framework, but during execution i am getting an error like

An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open. occurred

```
//Controller    
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee employee = employeecontext.EmployeeDetails.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeID == id);
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
```

//Model Employee

```
 [Table("tblEmployee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

//Model Employee Context

public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
}
```

An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open. occurred

Comment: That looks like a basic connection string error. There may be an inner exception with more details. Show your connect string for starters.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=NAG1-LHP-N06742\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>